# How can i call multiple methods on background thread, in java Android. I need to call them at different instant of time

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, runnable

```
package com.example.understandingthread;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.nfc.cardemulation.HostNfcFService;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // method1();
        }
    };
    Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
    t1.start();
    //Doing some other operations i have to do

    Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // method2();
        }
    };
    Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
    t2.start();
    //Doing some more operations, some for loops which will give me data 
    //to pass in method 3
    Runnable r3 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // method3(parameter 1, parameter 2,parameter 3);
        }
    };
    Thread t3 = new Thread(r3);
    t3.start();


}
}
```

// Do i need to implement runnable for each method, or if i do it by extending thread class, do i  need to create 3 different classes if i have to call 3 methods.
Is there any other better method than i have used?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. If you want your methods called at specific instances of time, you can use the java.util.Timer class. This way, they'll run on one thread (the Timer's thread) one after another. With your implementation, their runs might overlap in time, as you create three different threads for them.

Comment: no i don't want it to run at a particular instant of time, i just don't want to call them at once , otherwise the solution will be like call all of them at once in run method of runnable interface. i want the first i call first method then i do some ui updation kind of thing then i call other and so on.

Comment: Then, what's wrong with the code you showed us?

Comment: I don't think it is a good way, there must be some better solution for this that i don't know.